# IK Constraints Swinging Around Wildly

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

My IK's are out of control. I've set up enough simple IK's to know how to do it correctly and I have not idea what's going on here. I've tried redoing the IK's, recreating the bones completely, but nothing has worked. After making this post, I'm going to try to remake the whole armature.

Blend file

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5117" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5117/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem here is your Control bone for those IK is parented with the IK bone. So simply clear parent it will slove the problem.
-Select FrontFoot.L bone
-Press Alt + P
-Choose *Clear Parent*
[image]
The IK work correctly now.
[image]

Comment: Lol jeez. Yeah I guess I was rushing through this one. Thank you!